# How would I apply this type of dupont wire to a 0.64mm SMD pin?

Tags: cables

While browsing for more robust solutions to those plastic dupont jumper wires, I came across these wires:

[image]

The [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1713975.pdf?_ga=2.190690216.2050209575.1518788890-140954625.1509405106) didn't really provide any information and I haven't come across these wires yet. I was wondering how are these applied to pins. I have 0.64mm square / SMD pins on my board. Do you just slide them over for easy reversibility or do they have to be pinched with pliers or perhaps heated?

Comment: You push them on, just as you would for wires where the manufacturer *didn't* cheap out on the housing.

Comment: These are for testing and prototyping, not for production. So yes, "you just slide them over".

Comment: Thanks! And no I would never consider this for production! :-)

Comment: I hope the terminals are thru hole.  SMD will be rather delicate so the pads dont rip off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the plastic piece from your everyday jumper wires you'll find a small metal piece pinches on(seen in picture below). This is the exact same thing instead that over the metal piece is heat shrink instead of plastic 
[image]